# InAppSettingsKit ARC alternative

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

Hello is there a simpler alternative to InAPPSettingsKit which supports ARC.

I need only like 20 % from it's functionality, so something simpler will do the job. Or if you can point me to a tutorial where I can make my own Settings (with tableviews) it's going to be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InAppSettingsKit can be as simple or as complicated as you like, just use the standard controls and a simple settings.bundle/plist configuration if you don't need the extra functionality.

As for ARC, either use one of the ARC forks from Github, e.g. [tibr](https://github.com/tibr/InAppSettingsKit) or [Club15CC](https://github.com/Club15CC/InAppSettingsKit/tree/15CC-ARC-Version).

Or go to Project >> Target >> Build Phases and select all InAppSettings files and add the line -fno-objc-arc. This flag will tell the compiler to compile these files for non-ARC compatibility ([source](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/issues/92)).